# OWL 2 how to express equivalent class

Tags: owl

In my ontology I have a class `Parent` and a class `Child`. I have an object property `isChildOf(Child, Parent)`.

I'd like to express a new class, `FatherWithTwoOrMoreChildren`, which corresponds to the class of `Parent` having at least 2 `Child`.

```
Declaration(Class(p:FatherWithTwoOrMoreChildren))
SubClassOf(p:FatherWithTwoOrMoreChildren 
ObjectSomeValueFrom(ObjectPropertyAssertion(ObjectMinCardinality(2 
p:isChildOf) owl:Thing))
```

My doubt is if I'm expressing it correctly, or if calling `ObjectPropertyAssertion` I'm changing `isChildOf`'s definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to define `:FatherWithTwoOrMoreChildren` as :

```
:hasChild owl:inverseOf :isChildOf
:FatherWithTwoOrMoreChildren owl:equivalentClass (:hasChild min 2 :Child)
```

But maybe don't you want to create a `hasChild` objectproperty.